# My Vimeo embedded object is hiding my subnav (flash object)

Tags: css, flash, vimeo, embedded-video

http://beta.helpcurenow.org/media/videos/

If you go to this page, you'll see I have a main video window that loads whatever the newest video is, or one that you click from the thumbnails below.

However, the Vimeo embedded object is hiding my subnav when you attempt to get to the drop down menus at the top.

I dealt with this issue already for IE7 and the bug that causes absolutely positioned subnavs of this type to fall behind content after it, but that fix is not working here, likely because this is not an IE issue, it's a flash issue.

Is this just the consequences of using an embedded flash player from Vimeo (or others)?

Is there any type of fix for this issue? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into your object:

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>`

This will alter the window mode of the flash object and make it transparent, basically telling it to respect stacking order rules defined in the CSS.

**Edit**: I just wrote an article with a demo and explanation of why this happens - http://work.arounds.org/layering-flash-under-html-layering-html-over-flash/

Comment: @JAG, you should show your gratitude by giving the answer an upvote.